# Under what conditions is a subpanel to have a separate grounding rod?

Tags: grounding, grounding-and-bonding

Does a subpanel need a grounding rod when the subpanel is within the same structure as the main panel?

Does a subpanel need a grounding rod when it is in an outbuilding?

Are there any distance considerations?

Comment: No, but it needs to be connected to the building's grounding system and associated rods or other electrodes. Yes, No. And neutral and ground are always separate in a sub-panel, regardless of whether it needs a rod. And usually if it needs *a* rod, it needs TWO.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, when does it need two?  Just based upon the 25 ohm rule?

Answer (score 2):

No. Post-2008, system safety ground (Equipment Grounding Conductor) must be carried to all panels in the entire distribution, whether in the same building or a different building.

*And also*, each building needs a set of ground rods. But only 1 per building.

Officially "a breezeway" will turn 2 buildings into 1 building for NEC reasons.  However, your AHJ may view that differently if you have a vast interconnected complex.

Generally speaking, too many ground rods "can't hurt, might help".